# Binary conversion in c (to 12 char, base 36, left zero padded)

Tags: c

What would be the most efficient func to convert a binary to  12 character, base 36, left zero-padded? At the moment I have come up with this:

```
int transform_id (int64_t id_value, char* str) {

  char  num[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ??";
  int   i;

    for (i = 11; i >= 0; id_value /= 36) {
        str [i--] = num [id_value % 36];
    }

    str [12] = 0;
    return (12);

}
```

... which seems to work but i'm not sure if there is a far superior method O(n) wise

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code. It should be posted on [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: 1) `lldiv_t lldiv(id_value, 36);` to generate both quotient and remainder may help.  2) If native `int` smaller `int64_t`, breaking into `int` math as `id_valu` becomes smaller may help too.  3) Calc 3 digits at a time - again using smaller `unsigned` width for the break the 0 to 46655 into 3 digits.  4) I think you may need 13 digits.

Answer (score 1):

well, table lookup is the fastest method I think. The problem is base because it's not, well, "bit-aligned". if your base was 2^n, then you could use bitwise shifts and ANDs to get indices, and now you have to use division and deal with remainder